# Problem when add administrator for Analysis Server ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I'm trying to add a user as an administrator in Analysis Server, doing this:

```
1 - Connect - Analysis Server - Right click on the Instance - Properties - Security - ADD :
```

[image: add]

This number was already there, So when I click ADD  and insert the user to be administrator, I see this error:

[image]

It says in English:

> an error occurred in the system ( microsoft.AnalysisServices)

But what error? I can't add anyone. I can't even add myself ( I'm AD user of all servers ). Can't even add, too, the account I use to start services ( It has domain admin full privileges ).

Obs: This is our test server. We need to create analysis services objects via software. I'm trying to add the software user as administrator here to be able to create a cube.

**EDIT1**:

Trying to trace the error, I only get this:

[image: the same useless information]

The same useless information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days with this problem, I deleted that number, and could add users with no problem.